# How to retrieve SID's byte array

Tags: c++, security, winapi, authentication

How can I convert a PSID type into a byte array that contains the byte value of the SID?
Something like:

```
PSID pSid;
byte sidBytes[68];//Max. length of SID in bytes is 68
 if(GetAccountSid(
        NULL,       // default lookup logic
        AccountName,// account to obtain SID
        &pSid       // buffer to allocate to contain resultant SID
        )
```

{

```
ConvertPSIDToByteArray(pSid, sidBytes);
```

}

--how should I write the function ConvertPSIDToByteArray?

Comment: `68=SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you might be looking for is [ConvertSidToStringSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376399%28VS.85%29.aspx). The general idea is to convert the `PSID` struct to a `LPTSTR` which is in fact of type `wchar_t`. You can then convert this using standard functions to a multi-byte char array using [wcstombs](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/wcstombs.html) which will then give you the SID in bytes. Alternatively, you can operate on the `wchar_t` type directly and just write that out - there are functions for handling that. In either case, the result will be `UTF-16 LE` encoded and if you need to change from that you'll have to do a conversion.

Comment: Looking here:
http://www.secnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/topic10882.aspx
I understood that SID string's length is not the byte array's length:
(68)-- pure binary
(136) -- (68*2) = hexString
(184) -- SID String

So I want the shortest form...

Answer (score 3):

Use the GetLengthSid() to get the number of bytes you'll need.  Then memcpy() from the PSID.